# QML: passing RichText as PlainText

Tags: javascript, qml

I have a simple TextArea like this:

```
TextArea {
   id: my_text_area
   anchors.margins: 5
   anchors.fill: parent
   textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
}
```

The user can enter text in the TextArea. I now want to find patterns in the entered text and highlight them by making them bold, red or underlined.

I am passing the text to a js function like this:

```
Functions.doSomething(my_text_area.text)
```

The issue I have is this: 
I am searching for specific patterns in the text and the entire html markup of the RichText messes up the patterns.

Is there a function I have missed that allows me to pass the text in PlainText format? Or is there some "easy" way to remove all html markup with a javascript function?
Or is there another way around the problem?

What I tried so far:

I tried to set the textFormat to TextEdit.PlainText before passing the text, but that doesn't work. I also thought about having a RichText TextArea and a PlainText TextArea and displaying only one at a time (e.g. The user enters text into the PlainText Area and the program displays it in the RichText Area), but the problem with this is that the user should be able to edit the text once it has been highlighted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't pass area.text to the functions, it gives the raw content of the TextEdit, being it plain or rich text. If your area has RichText and you want to use the plain representation of it, use :

```
area.getText (0, area.length)
```

It will give you the characters of the content, excluding the HTML formatting tags.
But then you will need to do the mapping from plain text position and formatted text by yourself.

So if you need to replace 'foo' with '**foo**' you will have to do it on the area.text anyway, using some RegExp or anything else.

Comment: thanks a lot. I must have been a little blind while trying to solve the problem :/.